# Pure javascript html 5 text type number range validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

I have a page that I'm building and do not have the option to import jQuery. I need to be able to determine if any textboxes are marked with an html 5 invalid psuedoclass using a pure javascript solution. Said more simply: I need to use javascript to determine if any of the textboxes have the red outline that textboxes get marked with if you, for example, put text in a type=number field.

Just for completeness, here's some sample code:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="31" id="txtCalDays" placeholder="##"/>
<input type="button" onclick="ValidateForm()"/> 
...
<script>
...
function ValidateForm(){
    ... //magic happens here
    if (numberInvalidTextboxes == 0){ SubmitFormViaAjax(); }
}
```

Comment: ":invalid" is a css selector you can use to find them

Comment: To add to @dandavis 's answer, `:invalid` is supported only from IE10+, if that's any consideration to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `checkValidity()` method to detect the validity of a html5 input element.

```
document.getElementById('txtCalDays').checkValidity()
```

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/k7moorthi/saobbfzo/

Comment: I'll end up going with this, iterating through each of the inputs in the containing control. I prefer the cleaner `input:invalid` pseudoclass solution but this is what I have to use since we still support IE 9. Thank you!

Comment: @MetalPhoenix You will still need to polyfill the `<input type="number">` like @hexaheart pointed out.

Comment: Just a note: checkValidity is not supported in IE BUT the other validation that I am doing makes up for that (both server and clientside) - they all work together to validate no matter which browser our staff is using. CheckValidity ends up working beautifully on every other browser except IE9 so this is a "win" solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Give an `id` or a `class` for each element and give the code this way:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById("theFrm").onsubmit = function () {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".input");
    for (var i in inputs)
      if (!inputs[i].validity.valid) {
        inputs[i].focus();
        return false;
      }
    ajaxSubmit();
    return false;
  };
};
```

```css
*:invalid, .error {border: 1px solid #f00; background: #f99;}
```

```html
<form action="" id="theFrm">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="31" id="txtCalDays" required placeholder="##" class="input" />
  <input type="submit" onclick="ValidateForm()" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: how does that implement html5 validation state?

Comment: @dandavis It will not allow the user to submit, by returning false.

Comment: Not only does this not use the valid/invalid state of the controls, it ties the script to the shape of the database. This is not acceptable since the amount of changes that need to be made when a column is added or removed must be minimized.

Comment: The updated answer STILL ignores the html 5 validation types. Adding a class to a control isn't the solution I need

Comment: @MetalPhoenix Updated again. Sorry.

Comment: The problem is this: `if ((txtCalDays.value < 0 && txtCalDays.value > 31) || txtCalDays.value.trim() == 0)`

Checking each and every control on the page is not acceptable. If there are 15 columns in the database, it makes better sense to check if ANY of the controls are invalid instead of removing the html 5 validation constraints and manually checking the values of the data.

Comment: @MetalPhoenix Can we use `validity.valid`? I can give you an example.

Comment: @MetalPhoenix Have a look at my updated answer please.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

`document.querySelectorAll('input:invalid')` return an array of all invalid input in the document, you can replace `document` by any type of node.

Add some css like `:invalid{background-color: rgba(250,0,0,.15);}` can be usefull also.

Comment: The `document.querySelectorAll('input:invalid').length > 0` solution is exactly what I was looking for and seems to work in firefox, chrome, and IE. Thank you.

Comment: Older version of IE doesn't support html5 input anyway :P

Comment: Okay, not what I was looking for. We still have to support a few computers with IE 9.

Comment: IE9 is ok with `:invalid` & `querySelectorAll`, only the `type="number"` isn't supported :/.

Comment: @Tim MetalPhoenix doesn't want to use jQuery that's probably the case for any lib.

Comment: @hexaheart You are right. But I'm sure there are others.

Answer (score 1):

I think the method you are looking for is checkValidity().

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/checkValidity

```js
;(function(w,d,undefined) {
  
  "use strict";
  
  function init() {
    // bind checkValidity() to button click
    d.querySelector("button.validity").addEventListener("click",checkValidity);
  }
  
  // loop through inputs and check validity
  var checkValidity = function() {
    var inputs = d.querySelectorAll('#f input');
    [].forEach.call(inputs,function(input) {
      alert( 'validness of ' + input.name + ' is ' + input.checkValidity() );
    });
  };
  
  // inititalize only when the DOM is ready
  d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",init);
  
})(window,document);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #DEF;
}
#f {
  width: 222px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2em;
  margin: auto;
}
#f > * {
  margin-bottom: .25em;
}
#f label, button {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 100px;
}
#f input, #f button {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<form id="f">
  
  <label for="tel">Just Numbers</label><input type="text" name="numbrz" pattern="\d+" />
  
  <label for="email">Email</label><input type="email" name="email" />
  
  <button type="button" class="validity">check validity</button>
  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ValidityState.valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState):

```js
var input = document.getElementById("test");

input.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
    
    if (test.validity.valid) {
        input.classList.add("valid");
        input.classList.remove("invalid");
    } else {
        input.classList.add("invalid");
        input.classList.remove("valid");
    }
});
```

```css
input.invalid {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="test">
```

Now you can check for the `input.invalid` instead of `input:invalid` selector.

To make this cross-browser, you can bind this event listener in addition to the `change` event, also to the `input`, `blur`, `keyup` and `keydown` events. Furthermore you will need a polyfill for [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#JavaScript_shim_for_other_implementations).